# Performing the same mathematical operation on many attributes at once with QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, layers, fields-attributes

How to perform the same mathematical operation on many attributes at once? I have multiple numeric attributes and I would like to divide the value of each by the polygon area which is stored in a separate attribute.

There are dozens of these attributes to convert and I can do it manually for each one, but I would like to know if I can calculate it in a simple way? All calculations are performed on one layer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option is to use Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>[Refactor Fields](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#qgisrefactorfields)</kbd>. In the field `Source Expression`, include your mathematical operation. In the field `"Name"`, you can change the field name (or leave it as it is). Depending on the operation, you might also want to change the field type:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I can suggest a PyQGIS approach.

It utilizes the [`$area`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#area) function inside the [`QgsExpression()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsExpression.html) class.

Let's assume this is an attribute table of the original *'lines'* layer, see the image below.

[image: input]

### Case 1. If there are only several expressions

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsExpression, QgsExpressionContext, QgsExpressionContextUtils

# refer to a layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("lines")[0]

# set up expressions including two desired fields
expression1 = QgsExpression('"field1"/$area')
expression2 = QgsExpression('"field2"/$area')

# define the expression context to encapsulate parameters for evaluation
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

# start layer editing
with edit(layer):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(feat)
        feat["field1"] = expression1.evaluate(context)
        feat["field2"] = expression2.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like:

[image: result]

*Note: **Remember that applied changes can not be undone***. Also, be aware that the original field has to be of the *real* type.

P.S. I used the `$length` function instead of `$area` for my example.

### Case 2. If there are much more fields to consider

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsExpression, QgsExpressionContext, QgsExpressionContextUtils

# refer to a layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("lines")[0]

# fields that need to be modified
working_fields = ["field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"]

# define the expression context to encapsulate parameters for evaluation
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

# start layer editing
with edit(layer):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        # loop over each working field
        for field in working_fields:
            # set up an expression including multiple desired fields
            expression = QgsExpression(f'{field}/$area')
            context.setFeature(feat)
            feat[f"{field}"] = expression.evaluate(context)
            layer.updateFeature(feat)
```

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook | 11. Expressions, Filtering and Calculating Values](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) and include all fields you want to have unchanged (or `*` for all) and the fields, combined with the mathematical operation, like:

```sql
select *, "field_1"/10 as "new_field_1", "field_2/10" as "new_field_2"
from "my_layer"
```

to divide by 10 fields `field_1` and `field_2`.